# XSL Sort Numbers Separated by Periods

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a problem with sorting numbers, separated by periods (e.g. 1, 2.1, 1.1, 1.3). I found a solution here [XSL recursive sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643621/xsl-recursive-sort). That is what I need, slightly different. 
In my xml, tags are like

```
 <root>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>A</name>
       <val>1.1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>B</name>
       <val>1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="level"/>
       <name>C</name>
       <val>test</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>D</name>
       <val>1.2.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>E</name>
       <val>1.2.1</val>
    </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>F</name>
       <val>1.2</val>
    </row>
 </root>
```

and I want to sort all rows which col/@name = "rank" based on "val" tags. Is it possible to get the output with only modifying accepted answer in linked question? If not, is there any solution with xsl version 1 (or 2 if there is none).
The output I need is like:

```
<ul>
   <li>1 - B
     <ul>
       <li>1.1 - A</li>
       <li>1.2 - F
          <ul>
             <li>1.2.1 - E</li>
             <li>1.2.2 - D</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>      
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Update I**: So based on michael.hor257k's answer, this is the **solution** I was looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row[not(contains(val, '.'))][contains(col/@name, 'rank')]">
          <xsl:sort select="val" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
    </body>    
    </html>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <li>
      <xsl:variable name="parent" select="concat(val, '.')" />
      <xsl:value-of select="./name"/> - <xsl:value-of select="./val"/>
      <xsl:if test="../row[starts-with(val, $parent)][not(contains(substring-after(val, $parent), '.'))][contains(col/@name, 'rank')]">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../row[starts-with(val, $parent)][not(contains(substring-after(val, $parent), '.'))][contains(col/@name, 'rank')]">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-after(val, $parent)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update II**: Thanks to Dimitre Novatchev, I have a better **solution** which I think it is the best answer. So, I am trying to understand it, after that I'll check it as the accepted answer.

**Update III**: I accepted the answer michael.hor257k posted because it was what I needed. I know there is no jumps in orders of ranks in my xml but as Dimitre Novatchev mentioned, if there is, like having 1.3.2 with no 1.3 there will be a problem with this solution and you can use the complete answer which Dimitre Novatchev posted.

Comment: It seems you want much more than just **sort** them: you also want to **nest** them according to their hierarchy.

Comment: If you sort them, I'll try to do the rest. :-D Actually, it isn't that important. also the "name" tags values. (I just want to show how the numbers should be sorted)  @michael.hor257k

Comment: There is a better solution than the accepted one -- it doesn't impose any limitations on the XML document.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you @DimitreNovatchev. I did realize that each rank (on that accepted answer) must follow another rank but in my case, there is no jumping in the ranks and that was pretty much what I needed so I accepted that. I'll check yours and if it was more suitable (which I guess it is), I'll change the solution. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @Warjeh, I added a second part to the solution and it now produces exactly the wanted `<ul> ... </ul>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row[not(contains(val, '.'))]">
            <xsl:sort select="val" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="concat(val, '.')" />
    <item val="{val}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../row[starts-with(val, $parent)][not(contains(substring-after(val, $parent), '.'))]">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-after(val, $parent)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following input example:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>A</name>
       <val>1.1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>B</name>
       <val>1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>F</name>
       <val>1.10</val>
    </row>
   <row>
       <col name="level"/>
       <name>C</name>
       <val>2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>D</name>
       <val>1.2.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>E</name>
       <val>1.2.1</val>
    </row>
   <row>
       <col name="rank"/>
       <name>F</name>
       <val>1.2</val>
    </row>
 </root>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
   <item val="1">
      <item val="1.1"/>
      <item val="1.2">
         <item val="1.2.1"/>
         <item val="1.2.2"/>
      </item>
      <item val="1.10"/>
   </item>
   <item val="2"/>
</list>
```

This works recursively and there is no limit on the number of levels. Note however, that each item (other than "ancestor" items that do not contain a dot) must have a parent.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed but there is some parts that you didn't pay attention like you didn't eliminate the rows with <col name="level"/>. I am going to write what I needed based on your solution and I hope that I don't waste your code.

Comment: I have purposefully ignored all things that weren't essential to demonstrating the method. It should be trivial to make the necessary adaptations. I have also ignored your boast that you'll "do the rest" after the records are sorted. Sorting is the easy part here (as I believe you're beginning to find out). If all you wanted to do is sort the rows, you could just reformat the numbering from "1.2.3" to say "001002003" and sort the result alphabetically.

Comment: I know you could do what I did and posted in my question and of course I didn't mean to boast about anything. As you can see, I am new to xslt, even I couldn't change the linked solution for my purpose. But it is fun for me to try what I can do. Your answer is the answer I was looking for, and I accepted that, but later I changed it to not accepted because another answer published. And really? I don't know which to choose, which I needed or the one is more complete maybe for other people. :) Again, thanks and <3

Comment: You can accept any answer you like, without giving reasons to anyone. But you should choose the solution that solves **your problem** with minimum effort and maximum clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Is the number of levels known? If so, in XSLT 2.0 you could use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="row[col/@name = 'rank']">
<xsl:sort select="xs:integer(tokenize(val, '\'.')[1])"/>
<xsl:sort select="xs:integer(tokenize(val, '\'.')[2])"/>
<xsl:sort select="xs:integer(tokenize(val, '\'.')[3])"/>
</xsl:apply-templates/>
```

for three levels. In XSLT 3.0 you could even do it with the `sort` function for any level: `<xsl:apply-templates select="sort(row[col/@name = 'rank'], function($row) { tokenize($row/val, '\.')!xs:integer(.) })">` although as you also want to nest I think using a recursive function doing

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$rows" group-by="xs:integer(tokenize(val, '\.')[1])"><xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>...</xsl:for-each-group>
```

is more suitable in XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 then pure sorting.

A complete stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:nest" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="rows" as="element(row)*"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:nest($rows, 1)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="mf:nest" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="rows" as="element(row)*"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$rows" group-by="xs:integer(tokenize(val, '\.')[$level])">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <li>
                <xsl:variable name="item" select="current-group()[not(tokenize(val, '\.')[$level + 1])]"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$item/concat(name, ' - ', val)"/>
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:sequence select="mf:nest(current-group() except $item, $level + 1)"/>
                    </ul>
                </xsl:if>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:nest(row[col/@name = 'rank'])"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it transforms the input

```
<root>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>A</name>
        <val>1.1</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>B</name>
        <val>1</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="level"/>
        <name>C</name>
        <val>test</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>D</name>
        <val>1.2.2</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>E</name>
        <val>1.2.1</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>foo</name>
        <val>2</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>bar</name>
        <val>1.10</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>F</name>
        <val>1.2</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>F</name>
        <val>1.10.1</val>
    </row>
</root>
```

into the result

```
<ul>
   <li>B - 1
      <ul>
         <li>A - 1.1</li>
         <li>F - 1.2
            <ul>
               <li>E - 1.2.1</li>
               <li>D - 1.2.2</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>bar - 1.10
            <ul>
               <li>F - 1.10.1</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>foo - 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Number of levels? Not necessarily. I think this answer is a good start for me to learn XSLT 2.0 or 3.0. Thank you very much. :-) I tried to change the linked solution but I couldn't, so my priority was that code and I am going to accept another answer as the solution, but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with sorting numbers, separated by periods (e.g. 1,
>   2.1, 1.1, 1.3). I found a solution here [**XSL recursive sort**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643621/xsl-recursive-sort).

**Part I. The sorting**

It is very easy to adapt the original solution to the new case. **Unlike the accepted answer, this solution sorts correctly XML documents**, where there is

```
<val>1.3.2</val>
```

but there is no

```
<val>1.3</val>
```

See Part II for transforming the sorted result into the wanted nested list structure.

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(concat(val, '.'), '.')" 
                     data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:param name="prefix" select="''"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- end of recursion, there isn't any more row with more chunks -->
            <xsl:when test="val = substring($prefix, 1, string-length($prefix)-1)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="chunk" select=
                 "substring-before(concat(substring-after(val, $prefix), '.'), '.')"/>
                <!-- this tests for grouping row with same prefix, to skip duplicates -->
                <xsl:if test=
                "not(preceding-sibling::row[starts-with(val, concat($prefix, $chunk))])">
                    <xsl:variable name="new-prefix" 
                                          select="concat($prefix, $chunk, '.')"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=
              "../row[starts-with(val, $new-prefix) or val = concat($prefix, $chunk)]">
                        <xsl:sort select= 
              "substring-before(concat(substring-after(val, $new-prefix), '.'), '.')" 
                                  data-type="number"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$new-prefix"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** -- note there is `<val>1.3.2</val>` but there is no `<val>1.3</val>` and the accepted answer doesn't produce correct result -- actually deletes the whole `<row>` having a `<val>1.3.2</val>` child:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>A</name>
        <val>1.1</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>B</name>
        <val>1</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>F</name>
        <val>1.10</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="level"/>
        <name>C</name>
        <val>2</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>D</name>
        <val>1.2.2</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>D</name>
        <val>1.3.2</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>E</name>
        <val>1.2.1</val>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="rank"/>
        <name>F</name>
        <val>1.2</val>
    </row>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correctly sorted result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>B</name>
      <val>1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>A</name>
      <val>1.1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>F</name>
      <val>1.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>E</name>
      <val>1.2.1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>D</name>
      <val>1.2.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>D</name>
      <val>1.3.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>F</name>
      <val>1.10</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="level"/>
      <name>C</name>
      <val>2</val>
   </row>
</root>
```

---

**Finally, one more refactoring: eliminating all XSLT conditional operators**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
                <xsl:sort select="substring-before(concat(val, '.'), '.')" 
                          data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:param name="prefix" select="''"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vHasChildren" select=
                           "not(val = substring($prefix, 1, string-length($prefix)-1))"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()[not($vHasChildren)]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="chunk" 
             select="substring-before(concat(substring-after(val, $prefix), '.'), '.')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="new-prefix" select="concat($prefix, $chunk, '.')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select= "self::node()
            [$vHasChildren 
           and not(preceding-sibling::row[starts-with(val, concat($prefix, $chunk))])
            ]
             /../row[starts-with(val, $new-prefix) or val = concat($prefix, $chunk)]">
            <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$new-prefix"/>
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
                "substring-before(concat(substring-after(val, $new-prefix), '.'), '.')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Part II: Transforming the sorted, flat result into a nested list structure**

Here we start with the result of the transformation produced in Part I, and from it we produce the wanted nested list structure. The sorted flat result we have so far is:

```
<root>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>B</name>
      <val>1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>A</name>
      <val>1.1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>F</name>
      <val>1.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>E</name>
      <val>1.2.1</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>D</name>
      <val>1.2.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>D</name>
      <val>1.3.2</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="rank"/>
      <name>F</name>
      <val>1.10</val>
   </row>
   <row>
      <col name="level"/>
      <name>C</name>
      <val>2</val>
   </row>
</root>
```

**We use this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "row[not(substring-before(concat(val, '.'), '.') 
              = substring-before(concat(preceding-sibling::row[1]/val,'.'),'.'))]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pPrefix" select="''"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </list>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:param name="pPrefix"/>
    <item val="{val}">
      <xsl:variable name="vnewPrefix" select="concat($pPrefix, val, '.')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vcurrentVal" select="val"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::row
                  [starts-with(val, concat($vcurrentVal,'.'))
                 and
                   (string-length(val) - string-length(translate(val,'.','')) 
                    = 1 + string-length($vcurrentVal) - string-length(translate($vcurrentVal,'.','')
                    )
                   or
                    not(starts-with(val, 
                                    concat($vnewPrefix, 
                                           substring-before(concat(substring-after(preceding-sibling::row[1]/val, $vnewPrefix),'.'),'.'),
                                                            '.')
                                    )
                        )
                   )
                  ]">
         <xsl:with-param name="pPrefix" select="$vnewPrefix"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result of applying this transformation on the above XML document is the wanted nested list structure**:

```
<list>
   <item val="1">
      <item val="1.1"/>
      <item val="1.2">
         <item val="1.2.1"/>
         <item val="1.2.2"/>
      </item>
      <item val="1.3.2"/>
      <item val="1.10"/>
   </item>
   <item val="2"/>
</list>
```

We can similarly produce the wanted HTML, using this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "row[not(substring-before(concat(val, '.'), '.') 
              = substring-before(concat(preceding-sibling::row[1]/val,'.'),'.'))]">
       <xsl:with-param name="pPrefix" select="''"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:param name="pPrefix"/>
    <li> <xsl:value-of select="concat(val, ' - ', name, '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vnewPrefix" select="concat($pPrefix, val, '.')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vcurrentVal" select="val"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vnextInChain" select=
      "following-sibling::row
                  [starts-with(val, concat($vcurrentVal,'.'))
                 and
                   (string-length(val) - string-length(translate(val,'.','')) 
                    = 1 + string-length($vcurrentVal) - string-length(translate($vcurrentVal,'.','')
                    )
                   or
                    not(starts-with(val, 
                                    concat($vnewPrefix, 
                                           substring-before(concat(substring-after(preceding-sibling::row[1]/val, $vnewPrefix),'.'),'.'),
                                                            '.')
                                    )
                        )
                   )
                  ]"/>

      <xsl:if test="$vnextInChain">
       <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::row
                  [starts-with(val, concat($vcurrentVal,'.'))
                 and
                   (string-length(val) - string-length(translate(val,'.','')) 
                    = 1 + string-length($vcurrentVal) - string-length(translate($vcurrentVal,'.','')
                    )
                   or
                    not(starts-with(val, 
                                    concat($vnewPrefix, 
                                           substring-before(concat(substring-after(preceding-sibling::row[1]/val, $vnewPrefix),'.'),'.'),
                                                            '.')
                                    )
                        )
                   )
                  ]">
         <xsl:with-param name="pPrefix" select="$vnewPrefix"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
       </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the flat sorted result, the wanted HTML result is produced:

```
<ul>
    <li>1 - B
        <ul>
            <li>1.1 - A
            </li>
            <li>1.2 - F
                <ul>
                    <li>1.2.1 - E
                    </li>
                    <li>1.2.2 - D
                    </li>
                </ul></li>
            <li>1.3.2 - D
            </li>
            <li>1.10 - F
            </li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>2 - C
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are spending on this question. :-) I saw Part I last night and it was the answer. Of course, there are something maybe  I didn't clear enough like I only want the "rank"s not "level"s. I did that with adding [contains(col/@name, 'rank')] after "row"s.

Comment: And the second Part, sorry, I don't know how to use them. These two works on output of part one, right? It works OK when using sorted output as you mentioned above, but how can I get the first output and use them in just one xsl?

Comment: When I have some free time I will publish a separate, XSLT 2.0 solution, which should be a little bit shorter -- using xsl:function and not having to deal with RTFs (result tree fragments). I was under the impression that you needed an XSLT 1.0 solution, and your comment that you just use FF, confirms that. You won't be able to use an XSLT 2.0 solution in this environment -- no present browser implements XSLT 2.0.

Comment: So isn't that time consuming, sorting and then transforming it to html if I have a huge xml?

Comment: If i had no chance with XSLT1.0, yes, I can try another methods without FF, but I must learn them first. :-D So far, I am using the solution michael.hor257k wrote, because I know my ranks are ordered without jumping a level. You are so kind. :-D @Dimitre Novatchev

Comment: @Warjeh, Performing "multi-pass" transformation in XSLT 1.0 is a classic question and has many answers in SO. See for example this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/7642486/36305 So, your first pass is the sorting, which you have in an <xsl:variable> -- then you must convert it to a "regular node-set" using the xxx:node-set() extension function of your XSLT processor -- most XSLT processors support EXSLT, therefore one can use for these the exsl:node-set() extension function. Just try it.

Comment: @Warjeh, Re: "So isn't that time consuming, sorting and then transforming it to html if I have a huge xml?" It depends on the definition of "huge xml" and also on the definition of "time consuming". From the description of the problem, it is necessary to do the sorting. It is also necessary to produce the html. Is there any part of the solution that you believe can be avoided, or would take a lot of time and needs to be optimized? BTW, the accepted answer has `<xsl:sort>` in two different templates! Isn't this "time consuming"?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your chosen XSLT processor supports a numeric collation (a way of sorting strings in which consecutive sequences of digits are treated as numbers, so "Chapter 2" sorts before "Chapter 10"). For example with the UCA collation URIs defined in XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 this would be

```
    <xsl:sort select="val" 
         collation="http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes"/>
```

Numeric collations have also been available in Saxon for some years in the form

```
collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?alphanumeric=yes"
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to learn XSLT processors and other related stuff ASAP. Now, I know nothing about XSLT processors. :D I use firefox and just drag my xml there (after defining xml-stylesheet). Using this <http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_systemproperty.asp> it is Transformiix if i am right.

Comment: When posting an XSLT question it's always worth stating what the technology constraints are: the XSLT processors shipped with the browsers are now about 15 years old, and severely constraining. If you want something more up to date to run client-side you could try Saxon-JS; however, it doesn't currently offer either of the solutions I suggested (numeric collations, or the higher-order sort function).

Comment: My bad! I thought only the XSLT version matters. Next time I'll consider this and will mention I am using a browser (or any other processors). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And here's another candidate if you're able to take advantage of it: the new fn:sort function in XPath 3.1 allows use of a composite sort key so you can write

```
sort(val, function($x){tokenize($x, '\.')!number()})
```